# how to distribute a mongodb collection with a hashed shard key among several shards which have different disk spaces?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have several shards in a mongodb cluster, each with different disk spaces, for example:

- shard_0 100G
- shard_1 200G
- shard_2 400G

Suppose I have ~500G data to distribute into these shards, with a simple hashed shard key. Without Zone configuration, all the data will be inserted into each shard equally, so shard_0 will fail on disk full error. So I want to assign predefined Zones to these shards so that the data will be split to the ratio 1:2:4

But for hashed shard key, what is the actual value of MinKey and MaxKey? Can I use `-2^63` and `2^63-1` safely? Meaning to split the range [`-2^63`, `2^63-1`] into 7 equal ranges?

Comment: Hi @goldenbull, did you check [config maximum storage size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#change-the-maximum-storage-size-for-a-given-shard) if it helps? :)

Comment: @Ray I know this config parameter, but it does not meet my situation. The name `maxSize` is somehow misleading. See [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11441) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12494)

Comment: Not sure if I.understand your situation correctly.. is there some reason that the 1:2:4 ratio is preferred? For your 500 GB case, would it be good that it is a 1:2:2 ratio? (which the 2:2 is evenly distributed by the sharding engine automatically)

Comment: 1:2:4 is just an example, of course here maybe some other ratios more suitable for a real application. the problem is how to control the distribution manually.

Answer (score 1):

I made some experiments, it works as I expected.

`db0.ds0` is a collection sharded with hashed `_id` field.

I created 3 zones, split the range `[-2^63, 2^63-1]` into 3 parts with the ratio `1:2:4`, and assign them to the 3 zones one by one.

Here are some details:

```
db.printShardingStatus(true);
------
tag: Ratio1  { "_id" : MinKey } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("-6588122883467697152") }
tag: Ratio2  { "_id" : NumberLong("-6588122883467697152") } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("-1317624576693539840") }
tag: Ratio4  { "_id" : NumberLong("-1317624576693539840") } -->> { "_id" : MaxKey }
------

db.ds0.getShardDistribution();
------

Shard shard_2 at shard_2/node02:27017
 data : 3.99GiB docs : 4095 chunks : 88

Shard shard_1 at shard_1/node01:27017
 data : 2.04GiB docs : 2094 chunks : 47

Shard shard_0 at shard_0/node00:27017
 data : 979.04MiB docs : 979 chunks : 30

Totals
 data : 7GiB docs : 7168 chunks : 165
 Shard shard_2 contains 57.12% data, 57.12% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 1MiB
 Shard shard_1 contains 29.21% data, 29.21% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 1MiB
 Shard shard_0 contains 13.65% data, 13.65% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 1MiB
------
```